# use of "is" instead of "are" - i'm confused

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

"Is this the plans for the Death Star?"

i would use the plural form: "Are these the plans for the Death Star?"
is this just internet grammar or do i miss something?

from a current reddit topic:

https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/comments/4sznlc/is_this_the_plans_for_the_death_star/

Comment: Please correct typos and summarize what is in the link and explain what specifically bothers you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the discussion in the link you gave; however, it is possible that the question "Is this the plans for the Death Star?" is grammatically correct in one situation:

> If someone pointed to a packet or bunch of papers and asked the question, then the phrase *is this* refers to the whole (packet/bunch), whereas the plural *plans* refers to the contents.

Comment: I would use "Is this the *bundle/collection/sheaf* of plans..." in that context. Using is with the plural form "plans" without a collective noun interposing in between them sounds wrong.